# jQuery .ajax load function, how to pass in data and retrieve it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have something like the following:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "info.html?" + $(this).attr('id'),
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $('#list-content').load("info.html?" + $(this).attr('id'));
        }
    })
```

In info.html, if I get the document.href and try to parse it, I don't get info.html?..., instead, I get the URL of the containing window which is index.html. Question, how do I get the data trailing the 'info.html?''? Is this good practice? How else can I pass in data and how can I retrieve it from info.html on document ready?

One more question, is there a way to access the elements inside info.html after loading it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because ajax request are handled by the server and you are still inside index.html, which is on the client side.  You can access them via `$_GET` in php which is the default method for load. As for accessing data in  info.html, you can easily do it in a callback function after load.

```
$('#list-content').load("info.html?" + $(this).attr('id'), function() {
     // js stuff here
});
```

Comment: The callback function is in index.html; are you suggesting manipulating info.html within index.html instead of having a document ready function in info.html?

Comment: Yes, everything you have in info html can be put inside this callback function, or you can just put it in document ready inside your index.html file and use live/bind functions

Comment: I want something to load dynamically based on the 'id' data when info.html loads, but I don't know what event I would use for .live(). Ideally, I would do something like `$("#infobox").html("something that goes here on load")` inside the call back function, but nothing happens! Help?

Comment: Oh, it works now! I must have had some dead code in there somewhere, but the callback function from .load works and I can access the elements that were dynamically loaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i think this is more like something you want:

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "info.html",
      data: {
        id:$(this).attr('id')
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
          $('#list-content').html(data);
      }
    })
```

If I understand you correctly, you are currently on index.html and you want to grab info.html and put it in a div?  If so, this is how you do it.

I'm not entirely sure why you are putting GET params on the url though.  There is a data param in the ajax function that will automatically create your GET string, I put it in the example if that is what you want.

---

ANSWER TO BELOW QUESTION:

Well you'd want to use a server side language, php is a popular choice.  So you might want to consider renaming your file to info.php (don't worry, it will still work if it's filled with html).  Then you'll have access to the GET param in php, you can do something like:

```
<?php
$id=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;
?>
```

From there you can do whatever you want with $id, echo it, use it in a db query, etc.

Comment: My main question is, how do I access 'id' from info.html? Or should I do a callback function within index.html and manipulate #list-content from there?